# How to Commit node in JCRRepository

Tags: java, jcr

How can i commit a node in JCRRepositorty that will persist in all session.

Answer (score 2):

`node.getSession().save()`. See [save()](http://www.day.com/maven/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html#save%28%29). in jcr spec or javadoc.